# JPA2(JBoss7.1's Hibernate) entityManager.find() is getting data from Cache not from DB

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, jpa-2.0

I am developing a web application using JSF2, JPA2, EJB3 via JBoss7.1.
I have an Entity(Forum) which contains a list of child entities(Topic).
When I tried to get the list of Topics by forumId for the first time the data is being loaded from DB.

```
List<Topic> topics = entityManager.find(Forum.class, 1).getTopics();
```

After that I am adding few more child entities(Topics) to Forum and then again I am trying to retrieve list of Topics by forumId. Nut I am getting the old cached results only. The newly inserted child records are not being loaded from DB.

I am able to load the child entities(Topics) by using following methods:

**Method1:** Calling entityManager.clear() before entityManager.find()

**Method2:** Using

```
em.createQuery("select t from Topic t where t.forum.forumId=?1", Topic.class);
```

or

```
em.createQuery("SELECT t FROM Topic t JOIN t.forum f WHERE f.forumId = ?1", Topic.class);
```

I am aware of setting the QueryHints on NamedQueries. But em.find() method is in a super CrudService which is being extended by all DAOs(Stateless EJBs). So setting QueryHints won't work for me.

So I want to know how can i make em.find() method to load data from DB instead of Cache?

PS: I am using Extended Persistence Context type.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="forum", type=PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
protected EntityManager em;
```

Comment: Do you have a second-level cache or not? Show us the code of the Forum and Topic entities, and the code used to add a new topic to a forum.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the behavior of individual `find` operations by setting additional properties that control the entity managers interaction with the second level cache.

```
Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>();
props.put("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS);
entityMgr.find(Forum.class, 1, props).getTopics();
```

Comment: I didn't know about BYPASS, +1

Comment: props.put("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", "BYPASS"); is not working. getting same old cached Object.

Comment: Depending on your provider you may need to use the JPA 2.0 enum. See edit to my answer.

Comment: I think `CacheRetrieveMode` applies to the second level cache, while the stale date in this case comes from the first level cache inside the entity manager.

Comment: @sivaprasadreddy.k - you mentioned the find method is being invoked in a higher level service that your DAO extends. Did you change the call there?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the relation between `Forum` and `Topic` was only added in one direction in your entity beans? If you set the forum id on the topic, you should also add this topic to the `Forum` object to have consistent data inside the first level cache. You should also make sure that you are not using two different entity managers for the update and find. The first level cache is only kept per entity manager, another em can still contain an older version of the entitiy.

Probably unrelated, but with JPA2 you also have a minimal api to evict entities from the second level cache, which could be used after an update:

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getCache().evict(Forum.class, forumId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put @Cacheable(false) within the Forum.class.